# Generating PDF file in .NET

Tags: .net, pdf

I am using C# .NET 2.0.I want to generate a PDF file . I should write a text in the file.

What are the prerequsites we need to generate the PDF.

Any simplae coding samples will help me.

PLease suggest opensource libraries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go for IronPDF. JetBrains rocks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [PDFSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsharp/)

> PDFsharp is the Open Source library that easily creates PDF documents from any .NET language.
>   The same drawing routines can be used to create PDF documents, draw on the screen, or send output to any printer.

```
// Create a new PDF document
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

// Create an empty page
PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

// Get an XGraphics object for drawing
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

// Create a font
XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.Bold);

// Draw the text
gfx.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, XBrushes.Black,
  new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),
  XStringFormat.Center);

// Save the document...
string filename = "HelloWorld.pdf";
document.Save(filename);
// ...and start a viewer.
Process.Start(filename);
```

[Samples](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=24&Itemid=35)

Comment: v1.5 on GitHub https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: SharpPDF looks dead. Go with PDFSharp instead...

This question has been asked a few times on SO:

- [How do I programmatically create a PDF in my .NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-pdf-in-my-net-application)

[SharpPDF](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/) - with tutorials [here](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/Tutorials.html).

Comment: It is created for .NET framework 1.1.
Of course it can be used in other .NET versions, but still.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend **iTextSharp**: http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

It's a port of iText: http://www.lowagie.com/iText/

Comment: iTextSharp version after 4.7 are not free for commercial use.

Comment: The question was not free. The question was open source.

Answer (score 1):

PDFSharp was moved to a new [site](http://www.pdfsharp.net/MainPage.ashx).
Now it is avalaible with MigraDoc Foundation.

> PDFsharp is the Open Source .NET library that easily creates and processes PDF documents on the fly from any >.NET language. The same drawing routines can be used to create PDF documents, draw on the screen, or send >output to any printer.
>
> MigraDoc Foundation the Open Source .NET library that easily creates documents based on an object model with >paragraphs, tables, styles, etc. and renders them into PDF, XPS, or RTF.

[Here](http://www.pdfsharp.net/Features.ashx) are the main differences.

Answer (score 1):

**PDFSharp** library is really a nice one!

I have used it for quite a while now, and I find it flexible enough to fulfill your needs.

However there are [some aspects](http://kolezhuk.wordpress.com/2016/02/17/pdf-report-generation-in-asp-net/#more-209) of using it as a "standalone library" - e.g creating tables is a headache and there aren't much text formatting options. It is much better to mix it together with [MigraDoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) (an extension library for PDFSharp).