# Generate PDF files from asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I'd like to print receipts from my asp.net mvc app. For now I think my best option is to create PDF files, which are easier to handle when they are going to print them, because of the margins/headers/footers/etc.

I don't want to have them configure their browsers just so they can print my receipts, some of them are just not that smart.

Any other options?

What is the best (free)library/api to generate PDFs from an asp.net mvc app

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779430/asp-net-mvc-how-to-get-view-to-generate-pdf

Comment: I might not want to generate the PDF on a View, so it's not the same question.

Comment: @hminaya: then it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244109/generating-pdf-file-in-net

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had good success creating bar code labels in PDF format using [Report.net](http://report.sourceforge.net/) as well as [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/). For iTextSharp in particular, the API seemed easy enough and it worked well in our ASP.NET MVC application. Not a lot of documentation for iTextSharp so you have to look up the java documentation for iText (which it's a port of).

Bonus: They're both free!

Comment: iTextSharp releases subsequent to version 4.7 are not free if you're using them commercially.  The license has changed.

Comment: How did you get Report.net working with MVC?  I'm struggling to understand how to get either the ViewPDF or ResponsePDF outputs to convert to an ActionResult.

Comment: Scratch my comment above about using Report.NET with MVC.  See my answer for example code.

Answer (score 10):

Using [Report.NET](http://report.sourceforge.net/) the code to return their hello world example in an MVC action is:

```
    public void MyPDFAction()
    {
        Root.Reports.Report report = new Root.Reports.Report(new PdfFormatter());
        FontDef fd = new FontDef(report, "Helvetica");
        FontProp fp = new FontPropMM(fd, 25);
        Page page = new Page(report);
        page.AddCB_MM(80, new RepString(fp, "Hello World!")); 
        RT.ViewPDF(report, "HelloWorld.pdf");
    }
```

The return type of the action is void as the Report.NET code directly updates the response, which gets returned by default for void actions.  This opens up a pdf viewer directly from the browser.

To get the response returned as a page rather than a download replace the RT.ViewPDF line with

```
RT.ResponsePDF(report, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response);
```

However this method is marked as deprecated in favour of the one that deals with System.Web.UI.Page.  Unfortunately I don't know how to deal with a Page object in the context of an MVC app.

I've been unable to get Report.NET to initiate the download of a PDF file.

Download Report.NET [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/report/).

**Edit**  I've recently discovered [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) which seems to be more recently maintained than Report.NET.  It's also available under the MIT license.  You can download from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsharp/files/).  There's also an extensive [wiki](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki) with many examples.

Basic code to return a file as a download in MVC:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult MyPdfAction()
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
            PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
            XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
            XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.Bold);
            gfx.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height), XStringFormats.Center);
            document.Save(stream, false);
            return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "HelloWorld.pdf");
        }
    }
```

**Another Edit** If you're interesting in producing largely text based documents with tables, it's well worth checking out [MigraDoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDocFirstSteps.ashx) as it provides a useful abstraction layer on top of the PDFSharp primitives.  MigraDoc is included in the PDFSharp download.  You'll need to add the PDFSharp, PDFSharp.Charting, MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel and MigraDoc.Rendering projects to your project to get it all working.

Code to generate a PDF for download here:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult MyPdfAction()
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Document document = CreateDocument();
            document.UseCmykColor = true;
            const bool unicode = false;
            const PdfFontEmbedding embedding = PdfFontEmbedding.Always;
            PdfDocumentRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(unicode, embedding);
            pdfRenderer.Document = document;
            pdfRenderer.RenderDocument();
            pdfRenderer.PdfDocument.Save(stream, false);
            return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "HelloWorld.pdf");
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an absolutely minimalistic document.
    /// </summary>
    static Document CreateDocument()
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        Section section = document.AddSection();
        Paragraph paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
        paragraph.Format.Font.Color = Color.FromCmyk(100, 30, 20, 50);
        paragraph.AddFormattedText("Hello, World!", TextFormat.Bold);
        return document;
    }
```

**Summary** Having looked at a number of PDF solutions for C# MVC, I'm using PDFSharp / MigraDoc.  I've discounted iTextSharp and projects based on it because of the expensive licensing costs if you're using it commercially (€2500 in my case).  Report.NET was developed with ASP.NET classic in mind and hasn't received an update since 2006.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MVC 4, check this out: http://www.nyveldt.com/blog/post/Introducing-RazorPDF

Comment: This uses the .NET port of iTextSharp underneath.  Check the license out if you're intending to use this for commercial purposes.

Comment: @Rosdi your link is expire can you define your answer in brief

Comment: @Rahul, this is a snapshot of the original blog: https://web.archive.org/web/20200915013946/http://www.nyveldt.com/blog/post/Introducing-RazorPDF. However I no longer recommend anyone to use this since it is outdated. I recommend you to use Rotativa instead.

Comment: Here is Rotativa link: https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa

Comment: @RosdiKasim see my this answer I create a pdf successfulyy but issue is not save the project folder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64712303/how-to-save-pdf-inside-project-folder can you help

Answer (score 0):

I would use iTextSharp if you are looking to generate PDFs to print from, but as far as other options go, why not just use css to style a printer friendly option of the page?

Comment: Because I can't control what the browser puts on the footer & header of the page, like the URL and stuff...

Answer (score 0):

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DiplomaModel objdb = new DiplomaModel();
            return View(from Diploma in objdb.DiplomaList.Take(10)
                        select Diploma);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public FileResult Export(string GridHtml)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                StringReader sr = new StringReader(GridHtml);
                Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
                pdfDoc.Open();
                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
                pdfDoc.Close();
                return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "Grid.pdf");
            }
        }
```

@View part

```
@model AUC.CommonUtility.DiplomaModel


    @{
        Layout = null;
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>PDF Generate</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 9pt;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>Student</h4>
        <hr />
        <div id="Grid">
            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;font-size: 9pt;">
                <tr>
                    <th style="background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc">Student Name</th>
                    <th style="background-color: #B8DBFD;border: 1px solid #ccc">Father Name</th>

                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.DiplomaList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:120px;border: 1px solid #ccc">@item.DiplomaStudentName</td>
                        <td style="width:120px;border: 1px solid #ccc">@item.DSFatherName</td>

                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "ExportPDF", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <input type="hidden" name="GridHtml" />
            <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Export" />
        }
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                    $("input[name='GridHtml']").val($("#Grid").html());
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```