# Attach dynamic Table as pdf and send via emal in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email, pdf, attachment

i want to attach a dynamic table Generated through c# code, and attach it as a pdf document

and send it via email to customer in asp.net

please help

Thanks in Advance

Regards.
Zain

Comment: what did you try? there are libraries to generate PDF files and there are plenty of examples on how to send emails with attachments from a C# ASP.NET web application. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279953/how-to-send-an-email-with-attachments-using-smtpclient-sendasync and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244109/generating-pdf-file-in-net

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

[iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/):

iTextSharp is a C# port of iText, and open source Java library for PDF generation and manipulation. It can be used to create PDF documents from scratch, to convert XML to PDF (using the extra XFA Worker DLL), to fill out interactive PDF forms, to stamp new content on existing PDF documents, to split and merge existing PDF documents, and much more.

Also, Refer:

[Create PDFs in ASP.NET - getting started with iTextSharp](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/80/Create-PDFs-in-ASP.NET-getting-started-with-iTextSharp)

[Creating PDF Documents with ASP.NET and iTextSharp](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001758/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030911-1.aspx)